# Product view event

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer, page

I want to change the product price view in frontend when opening the product page like picture below.

[image]

What event should I use to get the price from this page?

Comment: What do you exactly want will you please elaborate your problem because for changing the price of your product you can change it from backend by editing your product in catalog & if you want to change it's front end layout than there is a different approach

Comment: I want to change the price only on frontend, because i tried to get data on the fly.

Comment: for that simply go to your admin side in that go to the product>catalogue & than select the product for editing & change the price it is that simple If it is not that what you want to do than Just put the Image that what exact change you want.

Comment: The solution you give is changed on backend too. And i already said i tried to get data on the fly.